# fitting two functions with common parameters to two different data-sets simultaneously using nls()

Tags: r, optimization, functional-programming, regression, nls

I have two functions

```
funk1 <- (t,a,b,c) { a* exp(-k*t)* b* exp(-c*t) }
funk2 <- (t,a,b,c) { (A*t^k +a)* b* exp(-c*t) }
```

where, k and A are known.
I am trying to estimate parameters a,b,c by fitting these two functions funk1 & funk2  simultaneously to two different data-sets Y1 & Y2 respectively.

```
Y1 <- seq(5*10^7, 1*10^7, -2*10^5)
Y2 <- seq(0.01, 0.85, 0.0042)
```

I am using Optim to fit the models by maximising joint likelihood. But the parameter values I am getting are pretty un-realistic. (I think optimiser wandering in wrong directions and finding local maxima and I can't use a gradient function.)

I wish to use nls() to fit these two functions to respective data-sets, 'simultaneoulsy'. I am not sure how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add more detail about how you are calling the functions in `Optim` and preferably use a **small** example to highlight the error.

Comment: @PierreLafortune -  But I want to use nls() rather than optim. So the question is about nls().   Still, In optim I feed a function which calculates log-likelihood by least-squares method and  I asked it to return -log-lik since optim by default minimises the function. I am not getting any error in optim, its just that the values that I get are un-physiological (yes, I am fitting some biological data). I am getting almost a log fold higher estimates than the expected values for one of the parameters.

Comment: You haven't provided `k` or `A`. Or the actual expression you used. So if your error is typographical or structural, there is no way someone can help you. I am asking you to add more detail to your question.

Comment: And further to Lafortune's remark: what do you mean by simultaneously?

Comment: @PierreLafortune Oh sorry for that. k=0.01 and A=1000. I understood what you were saying, but the problem is, I have simplified my functions here, since I just wanted to find if there is a method for fitting 2 datasets to 2 different models sharing all the parameters, simultaneously. I have never used nls() and I am a newbie to R. If you are interested in looking at my original functions and their optimization I can definitely provide you more details. But right now I am interested to know if nls() can be used in my situation. Sorry for any miscommunication.

Comment: @renatovitolo By simultaneously I mean that finding unique values for parameters that satisfy both the model-fits. Since, my 2 functions share all of their parameters it can be easily done in optim to find their joint-likelihood by feeding  product of their SSRs (least sqaure method). But since I havent use nls() before I am not sure how to do that using nls.

Comment: This is an interesting problem and I now begin to understand what you aim to do. However, your example above is not yet reproducible. So if I get it right, `funk1` and `funk2` are marginal likelihoods, sharing a common 4D parameter `a,b,c,t`, for a joint probability distribution that you wish to fit to 2 datasets. Problem is, I don't see the coordinates of `Y1` and `Y2` in the expressions of `funk1` and `funk2`: where are the datapoints?

Comment: Wait a second: perhaps `t` is the observation of `Y1` and `Y2` where you evaluate the likelihoods?

Comment: @renatovitolo yes, t represents time which is an independent variable for observations in Y1 and Y2. Sorry for my clumsiness! I should have explained the problem better...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121356/discussion-between-renato-vitolo-and-vitalsigns).

Comment: @renato vitolo : not cool man!

Comment: After 1.5 hrs chatting I still haven't got a working reproducible example out of you: not cool indeed. I suggest you carefully reformulate your problem here, making sure that whatever you post works straight away on anybody's   PC: see here for instructions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example